# event and transaction in vhdl(timing diagram)

Tags: vhdl

I tried to solve the problem, but I got a different table than the table that xilinx shows. I attatched both my answer and real answer. Xilinx shows that "out" is 'U' until 36ns, after 36ns, it is '1'. Can anyone help me about why the "out" graphics is not assigned any value before 36ns?(I think it should be assigned first at 20 ns).
[my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quRZe.jpg)
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Gxs.jpg)

Comment: If no delay mechanism is present, or if a delay mechanism including the reserved word **inertial** is present, the delay is construed to be inertial delay. ...Every inertially delayed signal assignment has a *pulse rejection limit*. If the delay mechanism specifies inertial delay, and if the reserved word **reject** followed by a time expression is present, then the time expression specifies the pulse rejection limit. In all other cases, the pulse rejection limit is specified by the time expression associated with the first waveform element. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a really good question. I initially thought you had done something wrong when simulating, but then I ran my own simulation and got the same result.

It turns out that the `a <= b after x` assignment uses something called the "inertial time model" by default. In this mode scheduled events will be cancelled if `b` changes again before `x` time has passed. The purpose is to filter pulses shorter than the specified delay. In your case this is what the simulator will do:

- At t=0, `out` is scheduled to change to 1 at t=20.
- At t=12, `tem1 or tem2` changes to 0. The scheduled change at t=20 is cancelled and a new change to 0 is scheduled at t=32.
- At t=16, `tem1 or tem2` changes back to 1. Again the scheduled change is cancelled and a new change is scheduled at t=36.
- After this `tem1 or tem2` remains at 1, so the change at t=36 is executed and `out` finally changes from U.

You can change to the "transport delay model" using `out <= transport tem1 or tem2 after 20 ns;` In this case your drawn waveform will match with simulation.

Comment: Thank you so much i got it :)

Comment: Thank you very very much, i've tried to understand this about an hour and now i totally got it.